# How to faster filter a range?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to filter a range (9 columns and 1400 rows) by values in a column (rng01)

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
db.Rows.Hidden = False
For Each cell In rng01.Cells
If Not cell.Value = "323" Then
cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
Next cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This works, but takes about 3-4 seconds.
Is there a faster way, pls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets see if I understand your question:  `rng01` is one of the nine columns, you want to filter so that only rows where the value in `rng01` = `323` are visible.

You can use `AutoFilter` for this.  You will need a header row above your data (but it can be blank).

```
rng01.AutoFilter
rng01.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="323", VisibleDropDown:=False
```

If the sheet `rng01` referes to already has an active `AutoFilter`, the first `rng01.AutoFilter` clears it.

Note that `rng01` is *one column wide*.

If in fact `rng01` referes to a range wider than one column, use

```
rng01.Columns(3).AutoFilter
rng01.Columns(3).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="323", VisibleDropDown:=False
```

Comment: chris, it works, but 'VisibleDropDown:=False' doesnt work. DropDownArrows are visible.

Comment: @chrisneilsen, my excel is also 2010. DropDownArrows are staying visible. Also, Data tab - Filter button is active (Yellow). When I deactivate it (click), dropArrows disappear.

Comment: @chrisneilsen, is rng sheet or range ? It doesn't work. This becomes complicated. Please see my next question.